# android pay update cart with shipping address amount after the MaskedWallet creation

Tags: android, android-pay, google-client

As per the Android Pay documentation at link : https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial#create_a_masked_wallet_request . I have to create a cart with estimated Shipping charges and taxes to create MaskedWallet. But I have a scenario where the Shipping charges and taxes varies with the Shipping address. So, is there any way to create Cart without Shipping charges and taxes and after the creation of MaskedWallet adding the Shipping Charges and taxes based on the Shipping address found in MaskedWallet. If yes, then how to update the cart in MaskedWallet with this values.

Answer (score 1):

The shipping price and tax for the MaskedWallet is NOT the final price that will get charged(it is used only for estimation purpose). The final shipping price and tax are actually determined when you make FullWallet request. For example:

```
LineItem shippingItem = LineItem.newBuilder()
                                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                                .setDescription("Shipping")
                                .setRole(LineItem.Role.SHIPPING)
                                .setTotalPrice("You final shipping")
                                .build();
LineItem taxItem = LineItem.newBuilder()
                           .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                           .setDescription("Tax")
                           .setRole(LineItem.Role.TAX)
                           .setTotalPrice("You final tax")
                           .build();

Cart.Builder cartBuilder = Cart.newBuilder().setCurrencyCode("USD");
cartBuilder.addLineItem(shippingItem);
cartBuilder.addLineItem(taxItem);
cartBuilder.setTotalPrice("Your total price including shipping and tax");

FullWalletRequest request = FullWalletRequest.newBuilder()
                                             .setGoogleTransactionId(googleTransactionId)
                                             .setCart(cartBuilder.build())
                                             .build();
```